# How can I get TElement from string myTElementName?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I want to create a generic query builder to entityframework. To the following method `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<TElement> Method (String, Object[])` I am trying to pass generic types. That is :

```
BindingSource mybindingSource = new BindingSource();

mybindingSource.DataSource = 
    con.ExecuteStoreQuery<**SomeMethod**(MyTypeName)>(
        myperfectWorkingSql, 
        myperfectWorkingSqlsParams
    );
```

How can I get TElement from string MyTypeName? How should be my SomeMethod() function? Or which methods should I use?

or the following code also gives error? Here am I wrong ?

```
 function fooo ( Type t) {

 BindingSource mybindingSource = new BindingSource();

mybindingSource.DataSource = 
    con.ExecuteStoreQuery<t>(
        myperfectWorkingSql, 
        myperfectWorkingSqlsParams
    );
 }

ERROR: this gives type t or namespace t can not be found !
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to get your type from string, it will be resolved during the runtime, so you can't do such things `con.ExecuteStoreQuery<t>`. However you can use reflection to invoke this method and provide type as generic parameter

[Refer to this answer on how to invoke generic method via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)